# Parquet `write_table` introduces keys of data type to the data when writing to output file

Tags: google-bigquery, parquet, pyarrow

I have an issue when writing data to parquet files. I tried with different `pyarrow` versions (both 2.0 and 3.0) but the results look the same.

Examples of how my data looks like:

```
test_data = {
    'dogs': [
        {'dog': 'frankie'},
        {'dog': 'ricky'}
    ]
}

other_test_data = {
    'dogs': [
        {'dog': 'rory'},
        {'dog': 'marko'}
    ]
}
```

Then, I reformat them to look like this:

```
dog_data = {
    'dogs': [
        [{
            'dog': 'frankie'
        }, {
            'dog': 'ricky'
        }],
        [{
            'dog': 'rory'
        }, {
            'dog': 'marko'
        }]
    ]
}
```

I define the schema:

```
dog_fields = [
    pa.field('dog', pa.string(), nullable=True)
]

dog_schema = pa.schema([
        ('dogs', pa.list_(pa.struct(dog_fields)))
    ])
```

I convert them to pyarrow.Table using:
`pq_table = pa.Table.from_pydict(mapping=dog_data, schema=dog_schema)`

Finally, I write to a file:
`pq.write_table(pq_table, 'dog_data.parquet')`

What I see in the file is this, additional keys called `list` and `item`:

```
{
    "dogs": {
        "list": [{
            "item": {
                "dog": "frankie"
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "dog": "ricky"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain please why the types of the data fields are added as keys to the data?

Is there a way around it?

---

EDIT

This is how I get the data with the `list` and `item` fields.
I install the package with `brew install parquet-tools`, and then run:

`parquet-tools cat --json dog_data.parquet`

The reason I chose to load the file like this is that I wanted to inspect what the contents are. The need came from the broken schema I was seeing when loading the data from parquet files to BigQuery. BigQuery doesn't understand the structure of the data and interprets the schema as following:

[image]

Annoying `.list` and `.item` things are added there.

Answer (score 2):

@christinabo the issue here is that the canonical way of representing a lists in Parquet is to use [three groups for a single list](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#lists).  The outer group has the name the user specifies.  The two inner groups are meant to be called "list" and "element".  pyarrow uses "item" instead of "element" by default.  So BQ is ignoring the fact that the nested groups are meant to be one logical type.

The behavior is somewhat controllable with [Enable List Inference Parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#parquet_enable_list_inference_flag)

(full disclosure I work for BQ and on Arrow)

Answer (score 0):

How do your get the the dictionary with the additional list/item?

As far as I can tell, converting your data to `arrow.Table`, saving it to parquet and reloading it yields the same results:

```
table = pa.Table.from_pydict(mapping=dog_data, schema=dog_schema)
pq.write_table(table, 'dog_data.parquet')
loaded_table = pq.read_table('dog_data.parquet')

print(loaded_table.to_pydict() == dog_data)
>>> True
print (loaded_table.to_pydict())
>>> {'dogs': [[{'dog': 'frankie'}, {'dog': 'ricky'}], [{'dog': 'rory'}, {'dog': 'marko'}]]}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned how I get it: I use `parquet-tools` from the command line to see the content of the file. The reason I'm doing this is to see what gets written there; ultimate goal is to automatically load this data from the parquet file to BigQuery which results in loading the data with a broken schema. Annoyingly, BQ doesn't understand how to avoid and interpret this list and item keys, and simply loads them along with the original names. Feels like a BQ api issue tbh, as pyarrow can reload them without problem, as you also showed.

Comment: What I mean is I end up with something like this: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/17#issuecomment-553986161, additional `list` and `item` key names.
Sorry if this seems like a different issue now, but it leads me to the conclusion that it has to be BQ.

Comment: can you update your questions with the steps to replicate the output using parquet-tools

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#type_conversions BQ converts all nested groups to structs.  The canonical encoding of Lists in parquet  [three grouping levels](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#lists) which pyarrow uses.

Comment: @MicahKornfield I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. BQ indeed converts groups to structs, but it mistakenly adds additional things to the name of the variables. In my example, I would like to have as names `dogs` and `dogs.dog` instead of `dogs.list` and `dogs.list.item.dog` that I now get. There must be something wrong with how BQ reads this data. Why does it add `list` and `item` to the original field names?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write with the parquet file with
`pq.write_table(pq_table, 'dog_data.parquet', use_compliant_nested_type=True)`

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_table