# Unnecessary .list.item nesting in BigQuery schemas from pyarrow upload dataframe with lists as columns. enable_list_inference partly works?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, parquet, pyarrow

So I am uploading this table to BigQuery with

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
pq_opt = ParquetOptions()
pq_opt.enable_list_inference = True
job_config.parquet_options = pq_opt  
job = self.client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
```

where say,I have a pa.schema with entries of the type:

```
("image_id", pa.list_(pa.string())),
```

And as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744696/parquet-write-table-introduces-keys-of-data-type-to-the-data-when-writing-to-o) I use enable_list_inference. Before using enable_list_inference the schema in BQ looks like:

[Schema without list inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHfeD.png)

And after I use it I get:

[Schema with list inference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2DIb.png)

So what's the reason I lose the list part but not the item part? I am passing a normal data frame with lists in some rows. How can I ditch the .item part and just have a column of REPEATED entries?

Answer (score 2):

This became too long for a comment but there are two potential things going on here (not sure if fixing either would help but it is worth trying).

- Pyarrow by default assumes columns are [nullable](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.field.html#pyarrow.field).  You can try making the top level non-nullable (and/or the inner string element non-nullable), if they in fact cannot have nulls, this should change schema inference.  BQ needs to maintain intermediate records (similar to parquet) to handle repeated elements that might also be null.
- The second thing to try is to set [use_compliant_nested_types=True](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html?highlight=parquetwriter#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter) when writing the pyarrow table.  this will change the inner element from "item" to "element" which is the correct name according to the [parquet specification](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#nested-types).  This might also affect things.  (BigQuery should support either so I think the first option is the more likely to work).

Comment: Here, is the gist for the same https://gist.github.com/Dminor7/8ff3fa034e991ac2839d66131fc004c5

Comment: If the inner element is "item" it won't work. Only "element".